# Are these "phrases" or "clauses" before a noun a modifier adjective?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, clauses, phrases, adjuncts

In these clauses or sentences "I love those "I love you" messages" or "I hate those "I love you" messages",

Is this "phrase" or "clause", "I love you", before a noun like "messages" an adjective modifier?

Comment: Direct quotes can be anything at all; they're not factored into grammatical analysis.

Comment: When you say "Direct quotes can be anything at all", What is "anything"?

Comment: I think I see that you said "direct quotes are not factored into grammatical analysis" but why are direct quotes not factored into grammatical analysis when I think they might be in sentences or they might be part of grammar, sentences, or words?

Comment: Because what comes out of our mouths and into our ears is not always language. One can't "say" a fortissimo B♭ chord played by a trombone quartet, but one can say any string of words at all and it can be reported as _They said `<random string of words>`_ and parsed as a simple sentence.

Comment: Considering that you said “they’re not shown in grammatical analysis”, what is “grammatical analysis”?

Comment: And I was thinking that I thought grammar would analyze or describe every sound that we would probably hear or word or signs that we would see.

Comment: Nope. Sorry. Grammar is just the (inferred) rules of behavior that lead people to speak ordinary (i.e, unremarkable) English (or any other natural human language). Description is part of it, and that takes terminology; since grammar is inferred, the terminology varies from grammarian to grammarian, though there is some agreement now and again. As for analysis, that depends on repeated patterns, and that takes more description in quantity and quality sufficient to discern the patterns, and new terminology to describe them. Don't hold your breath for the results; there aren't that many of us.

Comment: I thought this was “ordinary” English. If this isn’t grammar, what is this?

Comment: Why did you say “Don't hold your breath for the results; there aren't that many of us“?

Comment: (a) this is writing, not talking. there are no sounds to account for, (b) we're talking about talking about grammar, but we're not talking about grammar itself. I suspect you think knowing the names is enough, but in fact it's the patterns that matter. (c) _Don't hold your breath_ means "it will be a long time" (d) I'm a linguist and we're the people who actually figure out grammar (as opposed to teaching people English). (e) There really aren't very many linguists studying English, and they don't congregate here.

Comment: What is not talking? Why did you say “this is writing, not talking.”? I thought we would say that or I thought we would write what we say or I thought talking corresponds with writing. I think I wasn’t thinking knowing the names was enough and I think about the patterns too or I see or focus on the patterns. Why did you think I think “knowing the names is enough”? Why did you write “I'm a linguist and we're the people who actually figure out grammar“?

Comment: Writing is not talking. Talking uses the mouth and ears and makes noise. Writing uses the hands and eyes and doesn't make noise. Until you get that distinction right there's no point in talking about language.

Comment: I didn’t say writing is talking so I’m not understanding why you said “this is writing, not talking.”

Comment: Would you show me when I wrote “writing is talking”?